# Java SQLite JDBC executeQuery returns empty ResultSet of a non-empty column

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

My code:

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
Connection C = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");

Statement S = C.createStatement();
S.execute("CREATE TABLE NUMBER (VALUE INT(1))");
S.close();

S = C.createStatement();
S.execute("UPDATE NUMBER SET VALUE = 0");
S.close();

Statement S = C.createStatement();
ResultSet Value = S.executeQuery("SELECT VALUE FROM NUMBER");

if(Value.next())
{

    int Result = Value.getInt("VALUE");
    System.out.println("Success");

}
else
{

    System.out.println("Failure");

}

S.close();
```

I would expect the result of this code would be "Success", because it should retrieve the integer value 0 from the column VALUE in the table NUMBER. However, it instead prints "Failure". I cannot figure out if this is because the table is actually empty or because it just can't get the data or what. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are executing an `UPDATE` Statement, but in the order the code is presented, nothing is persisted in Table `NUMBER` yet, as the `UPDATE` statement is used to update *existing* records in a table.

Use an `INSERT` Statement instead, thus inserting data first, as only this way tuples get created in the table `NUMBER`. Afterwards, the `ResultSet` should not be empty anymore.

If you need to learn the concept as such, you could have a look at this [W3Schools guide](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp).